# QRTEngine - Simulating keypress with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

there's not a lot of documentation for this but I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm using the QRTEngine provided by the folks over at http://qrtengine.com/ for Qualtrics (http://www.qualtrics.com/) - a survey tool.

I have managed to set up a 'agree/disagree' survey quite easily (user presses the key 'z' for disagree and 'm' for agree)

The problem is that I need this to work on mobile too. Now I've tried the following:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
(function( j ) {
  j(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery

var e = j.Event("keyup");

e.which = 77; // # Some key code value

j( ".agree" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
       j(this).trigger(e);
    alert(e.which);
});


  });
})(j);
```

Which executes the alert but doesn't seem to simulate the keypress. I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something in regard to the QRTEngine I'm using.

Any help (ANY) would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is the alias for the Prototype framework in Qualtrics.  If you want use an alias for jQuery you need to make it something else like $j:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

EDIT: Maybe this is your problem...from http://bililite.com/blog/2015/01/14/rethinking-fn-sendkeys/ :

"Modern browsers won't let synthetic events (triggered with dispatchEvent) execute their default actions (meaning the action that would occur if the event was triggered by a user action). The Event object has a read-only field called isTrusted that is false for anything but unmodified user-initiated events. These are called "trusted events", and I understand the justification, but they go too far. It makes it impossible to implement a virtual keyboard, since triggering keydown or keypress events aren't trusted and won't insert the character (the default action)."

Check out the link referenced above for a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my original code with your recommendation. It still fires the alert but doesn't fire the function that the QRTEngine has attached to that keypress.

Comment: Just seen your edit @T. Gibbons. The project has been shelved for now but I'll check out the solution!